# How can I no print error of unix command fail from python command? /dev/null

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write this command. file doesn't exist.

```
subprocess.check_output("cat file | grep -w txt | cut -d '=' -f2", shell=True).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

I get this output:

> cat: file: No such file or directory

but I don't want this.
I tried redirect to 2> /dev/null

```
subprocess.check_output("cat file | grep -w txt | cut -d '=' -f2 2> /dev/null", shell=True).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

or catch exception by subprocess.CalledProcessError but didn't succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception within your python script? `try:` the piece of code and `pass` (or handle otherwise) if an `exception` occurs. Or check if cat file exists with the `os.path.isfile(cat_file)`

Comment: Do you know how do use with 2>&/dev/null on unix command with pipes @offeltoffel